# Clear float on Bootstrap col to center div

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm new to Bootstrap and have a problem which I have fixed using a work around - but I thought I'd see if Bootstrap has a built in way to handle this as it's a fairly standard issue  (I would have thought).

What I have is a simple login page and I want my login form to be centered at all possible sizes. I have used bootstrap css col-lg-4 coll-lg-offset-4 which should center the div but it does not due to a float-left that is included in all sizes of col. A quickfix was to create a css class and adding it to my col class:

```
.nofloat {
 float:none;
}
```

Is there a better way to do this without having to add to my custom css?

Here's the code for the form which won't center on large screens:

```
<div class="container-fluid">
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-4 col-lg-offset-4"> <!-- This is where I add my nofloat current fix -->
      <form role="form" action='<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);?>' method="post">
        <h2>Please sign in</h2>
        <label for="inputEmail" class="sr-only">Email address</label>
        <input type="email" id="inputEmail" name="username" class="form-control" placeholder="Email address" required autofocus>
        <label for="inputPassword" class="sr-only">Password</label>
        <input type="password" id="inputPassword" name="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Password" required>
        <div class="checkbox">
          <label>
              <input type="checkbox" value="remember-me" />Remember me
          </label>
        </div>
        <button class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block" type="submit">Sign in</button>
        <a href="./forgotPassword.php"><p class="text-center">Forgot password</p></a>
      </form>
    </div>
</div>

</div>
```

Comment: There js a clearfix class that clear:both :)

Comment: Thanks - yeah that seems to work. Not as clean as I'd thought for bootstrap. But as long as I'm not missing something fundamental about the offset that's OK

Comment: From what I can see your grid misses 4 cols. You have to get a total of 12 columns per row.

Comment: Thanks @PhilM. - the offset puts the equivalent of 4 columns on the left which is supposed to handle this sort of situation. I did indeed try your solution by removing the offset and placing <div class="col-lg-4></div> before and after my form but the same issue persists on large screens.

Answer (score 0):

The best solution to this from Phil's comment is using the Bootstrap 'clearfix' class to remove the float element on the 'col...' class as follows:

```
<div class="container-fluid">
<div class="row">
    <div class='clearfix'></div>
    <div class="col-lg-4 col-lg-offset-4">
      <form role="form">
....etc
```

The solution I refer to in the question that also works was to declare a new CSS class:

```
.nofloat {
float:none;
}
```

and use it in the HTML as follows:

```
<div class="container-fluid">
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-4 col-lg-offset-4 nofloat">
      <form role="form">
....etc
```